# How to save one price per row instead of all prices on one row?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm having all prices per product (`price['value']`) saving on one row, separated by commas.  What adjustment do I need to make in order for each price to be saved in the row underneath the previous price?

```
import mechanize
from lxml import html
import csv
import io
from time import sleep

def save_products (products, writer):

    for product in products:

        writer.writerow([ product["title"][0].encode('utf-8') ])
        for price in product['prices']:
            writer.writerow([x.encode('utf-8') for x in price['value']])


f_out = open('pcdResult.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

links = ["http://purechemsdirect.com/ourprices.html/" ]

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

for link in links:

    print(link)
    r = br.open(link)

    content = r.read()

    products = []        
    tree = html.fromstring(content)        
    product_nodes = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12"]')

    for product_node in product_nodes:

        product = {}
        try:
            product['title'] = product_node.xpath('.//p/strong/text()')

        except:
            product['title'] = ""

        price_nodes = product_node.xpath('.//ul')

        product['prices'] = []
        for price_node in price_nodes:

            price = {}
            try:
                price['value'] = price_node.xpath('.//li/text()')

            except:
                price['value'] = ""

            product['prices'].append(price)
        products.append(product)
    save_products(products, writer)

f_out.close()
```

Comment: Show your current output and your desired output.

Comment: 5 for ┬ú8.00,10 for ┬ú12.00,25 for ┬ú20.00,50 for ┬ú45.00,100 for ┬ú50.00,250 for ┬ú150.00,500 for ┬ú250.00,"1,000 for ┬ú425.00","2,500 for ┬ú850.00","5,000 for ┬ú1,400.00","10,000 for ┬ú2,450.00","25,000 for ┬ú4,900.00"

Comment: That's saved in one cell right now, but where every comma is should be separating into a new cell, stored in the row below the last price.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the correctly formatted desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try to take this row in your function:
        `writer.writerow([x.encode('utf-8') for x in price['value']])`
and turn it into:

```
     for x in price['value']:
         writer.writerow(x)
```